# not .isAfter jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show separate messages if a div exists after a certain div or does not exist based the end of an ajax function

Here is the code I came up with:

```
.ajaxComplete(function() {

// Pilots page code.
if ($('body').hasClass('page-pilots')) {

  $.fn.isAfter = function(sel) {
    return this.prevAll(sel).length !== 0;
  }

  $('#quicktabs-tabpage-107_display-0 .view-content').each(function() {
    if ($(this).isAfter("#quicktabs-tabpage-107_display-0 .view-filters")) {
      console.log(".view-content is after, hide message");
      $('.pilots-result-message').hide();
    }
    if (!$(this).isAfter("#quicktabs-tabpage-107_display-0 .view-filters")) {
      console.log(".view-content is not after, show message");
      $('.pilots-result-message').show();
    }
  });
}
```

});

The isafter is working, but I can't figure out how to implement a function which is the opposite (would be nice if there was a isNotAfter jQuery function).

I have also tried instead of the second if statement:

```
else {
console.log(".view-content is not after, show message");
$('.pilots-result-message').show();
}
```

Comment: @BernardoLima I have tried this. Does not work for me, I have added it to the bottom of the description

Comment: Works fine here, http://jsfiddle.net/4gbowsyr/, change bob to after, and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called isAfter(), you can check whether the next element of `#quicktabs-tabpage-107_display-0 .view-filters` is the current(`this`) element like

```
if ($('body').hasClass('page-pilots')) {

    $.fn.isAfter = function (sel) {
        return this.prevAll(sel).length !== 0;
    }

    $('#quicktabs-tabpage-107_display-0 .view-content').each(function () {
        if ($("#quicktabs-tabpage-107_display-0 .view-filters").next().is(this)) {
            console.log(".view-content is after, hide message");
            $('.pilots-result-message').hide();
        } else {
            console.log(".view-content is not after, show message");
            $('.pilots-result-message').show();
        }
    });
}
```